# JOOQ - Get temp table from meta()

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I have some code that creates a table, then a different code tries to load a `Table<?>` instance given that table name, using `DSLContext.meta()`

## Create Table

```
        DSLContext db = getDslContext();
        String tempTableName = "temp_" + System.currentTimeMillis();
        db.createTemporaryTable(tempTableName).as(select(fields)
                .from(downstreamTable)
                .limit(0)).execute();
```

## Get Table instance

```
        Optional<Table<?>> table = db.meta().getTables().stream()
                .filter(t -> t.getName().equals(tableName))
                .findFirst()
```

Expected - Table will be returned, however it is not found. Also the temp schema is not found in `meta().getSchemas()`

I know I can create a Table using `DSL.table()` however I want to retrieve all fields using table.fields(). Currently I need to create my own little Table class that will hold the name and fields but it feels very wrong.

The code above works if I create a real table instead of temp table. Is there a way to make it work using temp table, either by finding the table in meta(), or by creating it in a way that table.fields() will return the table fields?

## Versions

- Postgres 9.5
- Jooq 3.10.8
- Postgresql driver 9.4.1212.jre7

Comment: What database and JDBC driver / version are you using for this?

Comment: @LukasEder edited with version information

Comment: Probably unrelated, but: the driver version 9.4.1212.jre7 is quite outdated. You should use the current version 42.2